# Unknown type name error Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I have 2 Qt windows namely, `MainWindow` and `GraphWindow`;
The `GraphWindow` class has a range of `QCustomPlot` widgets where data from other classes will be plotted. In the `MainWindow` implementation file, I instantiate a `GraphWindow` object and pass its address to other classes, so that all plots will be generated on the same window. But my problem is, when I try to pass the address of the `GraphWindow` objects, Qt throws the following error;

> `Unknown type name GraphWindow`

I have included `graphwindow.h` in all there classes which uses the `GraphWindow` object.

This is `GraphWindow` class declaration;

```
#ifndef GRAPHWINDOW_H
#define GRAPHWINDOW_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <mainwindow.h>
#include <incomestatement.h>
#include <balancesheet.h>
#include <cashflow.h>
#include <dcf.h>
#include <QList>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QString>
#include <qcustomplot.h>
#include <QSharedPointer>
#include <QHash>

namespace Ui
{
    class GraphWindow;
}



class GraphWindow : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit GraphWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GraphWindow();
    void plotData(QStringList labels, QList<double> yData,QString xLabel, QString yLabel, QString slot);

private:
    Ui::GraphWindow *ui;
    QHash<QString, QCustomPlot* > dynamicWidgetHash;
    QStringList widgetStringList;

    QVector<double> setupXAxis(QStringList labels, QString slot, QString xLabel);
    void setupYAxis(QVector<double> yData, QString slot, QString yLabel);
    void setupLegend(QString slot);
    void setHash(QStringList widgetStringList);
};

#endif // GRAPHWINDOW_H
```

This is `mainwindow.cpp` where GrapWindow object is created;

```
void MainWindow::on_runButton_clicked()
{
    //Create grapher object and pass the address to all sub-classes to plot on the same widget
    GraphWindow graphWindow;

    if(globalPath.isEmpty() == false)
    {

        //Create input QXlsx::Document Object
        QXlsx::Document inputDoc(globalPath);

//      QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save File"),
//                                   "/home/jana/untitled.png",
//                                   tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));

        //Create financial statement objects and compute values
        IncomeStatement incState(inputDoc,graphWindow);
        incState.computePoints(MainWindow::pointsListINC_ST,MainWindow::incSettingList,
                               MainWindow::incItemList,inputDoc);
    }
}
```

This is `incomestatement.h`, one if the classes using `GraphWindow` object.

```
#ifndef INCOMESTATEMENT_H
#define INCOMESTATEMENT_H

#include <QString>
#include <xlsxdocument.h>
#include <xlsxformat.h>
#include <QVector>
#include <QList>
#include <pointssystem.h>
#include <graphwindow.h>

class IncomeStatement
{
    //Declare PointsSystem as FRIEND of IncomeStatement to access private members
    friend class PointsSystem;
public:
    IncomeStatement(QXlsx::Document& inputDoc, GraphWindow& grapher);

    //Public member function to be called from mainwindow.cpp
    double computePoints(QList<QList<bool> > userSettings, QList<QStringList> itemStringList,
                         QStringList comboBoxItems, QXlsx::Document& inputDoc);

private:
    int cursorRow;
    int cursorCol;
    double scoredPoints;
    double totalPoints;

    QStringList timelineList;
    QList<double> revenueGrowthArr;
    QList<double>costOfRevenGrowthArr;
    QList<double>operIncGrowthArr;
    QList<double>netIncGrowthArr;
    QList<double>totOperExpGrowthArr;
    QList<double>grossMarginArr;
    QList<double>opIncMarginArr;
    QList<double>netIncMarginArr;


    QXlsx::Format format(QXlsx::Document& inputDoc, int mode);
    bool setSheetName(QXlsx::Document& inputDoc);
    void process(QXlsx::Document& inputDoc, GraphWindow& grapher);
    int searchKey(QString key,QXlsx::Document& inputDoc);
    int findCursorPointRow(QXlsx::Document& inputDoc);
    int findCursorPointCol(QXlsx::Document& inputDoc);
    void revenueGrowth(QXlsx::Document& inputDoc);
    void growthComputation(QXlsx::Document& inputDoc, QString criterion, QList<double>&storageList);
    void marginComputation(QXlsx::Document& inputDoc, QString criterion, QList<double>&storageList);
    QStringList extractTimeline(QXlsx::Document& inputDoc);
    void writeStockAnalysis(QXlsx::Document& inputDoc, QList<QList<QVariant> > data);
    void writeStockAnalysisHeader(QXlsx::Document& inputDoc);
    void writePointsSumData(QXlsx::Document& inputDoc);

#endif // INCOMESTATEMENT_H
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: You have a circular header dependency..

Comment: My god I can't be this stupid :/ Thanks bro :)

Comment: When I started learning c++ 25 to 30 years ago I am sure that I did this dozens of times. These days it never happens to me.

Answer (score 2):

You should not `#include <mainwindow.h>` from `graphwindow.h`, it doesn't make sense if mainwindow shall use graphwindow.

If you need the include, something's wrong with your design.  In that case you might circumvent the problem by including `mainwindow.h` from the `graphwindow.cpp`, and providing forward declarations for everything needed from mainwindow in the `graphwindow.h`.
Anyhow, instead of circumventing the problem you might want to rethink the design...

Comment: You are correct, I don't use it, I have mistakenly copied it there; forward declaration meaning, declaring a object of `GraphWindow` in `MainWindow` declaration? Am I correct?

Comment: No, not really.  1st: I meant it the other way around - i.e. inside graphwindow.h you declare `mainWindow`.  2nd: you wouldn't declare an object, but rather the class itself, like: `class MainWindow;`

Comment: On a second note: if your project gets rather large, forward declaring classes instead of including their headers can optimize compile time.  But this only works if all you ever declare to be used of the included class are references and pointers.